# how to create dataframes with mutli index from python dicts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read information from some data, according to which I also create a dict. These look as follows:

```
('B60_L50', '128', 'CP', 'S5', 'side', '2022-05-05_20-04-42 S101_z200'): defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {200: 6.352113278610182}), 
('B60_L50', '128', 'CP', 'S5', 'side', '2022-05-05_20-04-42 S102_z200'): defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {200: 5.621293764849755}), 
('B60_L50', '128', 'CP', 'S5', 'side', '2022-05-05_20-04-42 S103_z200'): defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {200: 5.979359334924249}), 
('B60_L50', '128', 'CP', 'S5', 'side', '2022-05-05_20-04-42 S104_z200'): defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {200: 3.587064282376453})})
```

where  `('B60_L50', '128', 'CP', 'S5', 'side', '2022-05-05_20-04-42 S104_z200')`  is the value of the multi index.  `{200: 6.352113278610182}`  indicates the column name (200) and the value of the cell.
before i created a dataframe and inserted the values one by one, but with the amount of elements it takes much too long. Therefore I thought it makes more sense to create a dict from the data.

this is how i had built the dataframe:

```
    ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [coils, frequencies, polarisations, s_values, orientations, titles],
        names=["Coil", "Frequency", "Polarisation", "S-Value", "Orientation", "First_Row_Element"])
    df = pd.DataFrame(None, index=ind, columns=list(landmarks))  # Convert landmarks set to list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your data can be represented as a dictionary, you can use `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples` to create MultiIndex

```py
d = {('B60_L50', '128', 'CP', 'S5', 'side', '2022-05-05_20-04-42 S101_z200'): {200: 6.352113278610182},
     ('B60_L50', '128', 'CP', 'S5', 'side', '2022-05-05_20-04-42 S102_z200'): {200: 5.621293764849755},
     ('B60_L50', '128', 'CP', 'S5', 'side', '2022-05-05_20-04-42 S103_z200'): {200: 5.979359334924249},
     ('B60_L50', '128', 'CP', 'S5', 'side', '2022-05-05_20-04-42 S104_z200'): {200: 3.587064282376453}}

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d, names=["Coil", "Frequency", "Polarisation", "S-Value", "Orientation", "First_Row_Element"])
df = pd.DataFrame(d.values(), index=index)
```

```
print(df)

                                                                                       200
Coil    Frequency Polarisation S-Value Orientation First_Row_Element
B60_L50 128       CP           S5      side        2022-05-05_20-04-42 S101_z200  6.352113
                                                   2022-05-05_20-04-42 S102_z200  5.621294
                                                   2022-05-05_20-04-42 S103_z200  5.979359
                                                   2022-05-05_20-04-42 S104_z200  3.587064
```